# Radio Button in Datatable cannot be rendered in Safari/Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem in my html file. 
I have a datatable in the page, and each row in the table has a column which contains two radio buttons.  One radio button should always be selected.

The problem now is that everything works fine under IE8, but when I switch to IE9+/Safari/FireFox, the first pair of radio buttons in the table don't appear to be checked. I checked the source code, it does tell that

```
<input type="radio" checked  name="radio_10" onchange="chgRadio('aaa','2')" value="2"></input>
<input type="radio" name="radio_10" onchange="chgRadio('aaa','1')" value="1"></input>
```

So it's kinda strange why the checked button cannot be rendered on the page?

Here I attach the source code of this html file, in the code I include a jquery file in javascript, once I removed this file, all the radio buttons can be rendered correctly even under Safara/Firefox. 
So I just wonder is it an issue regarding compatibility between jquery and browser version? Is it helpful to do some changes in the css?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="jquery/ui/css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="jquery/datatables/css/mrbs-page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery/datatables/css/mrbs-table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery/datatables/css/ColReorder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery/datatables/css/ColVis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs.css.php" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/mrbs-print.css.php" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs-ie.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs-ie8.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs-ielte8.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs-ielte7.css.php" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs-ielte6.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<meta name="robots" content="noindex">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-datepicker-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui-datepicker-en-US.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var lteIE6 = false;
//]]> 
</script>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var lteIE6 = true;
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var lteIE7 = false;
//]]>
</script>
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var lteIE7 = true;
//]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  var lteIE8 = false;
  //]]>
</script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  var lteIE8 = true;
  //]]>
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    function init(params)
  {
  }
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/ColReorder.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/ColVis.mrbs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/FixedColumns.mrbs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/datatables/js/plugins.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datatables.js.php?area="></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/edit_users.js.php?area="></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js.php?area="></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js.php?area="></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/general.js.php?area="></script>


</head>

<body class="non_js edit_users">
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $('body').addClass('js').removeClass('non_js');
  //]]>
</script> 

<div id="contents">
<script type="text/javascript">
       var changes = new Array();
       function delConfirm(id,name) {
          var r = confirm("Are you sure to delete user "+name+" ?");
          if (r)
               window.location="edit_users.php?Action=Delete&Id="+id;
        }
       function delAlert(){
          alert("This is the last admin in the system, you cannot delete it!")
       } 
       function chgRadio(name,role){
             var group = new Array();
             var exist = false;
             for(i=0;i<changes.length;i++){
                  if(changes[i][0]==name){
                       changes[i].push(role==1?"user":"admin");
                       exist = true;
                   }
             }
             if (!exist){  
                group.push(name,role==1?"user":"admin");
                changes.push(group);
             }
       }
       function chgConfirm(Action){
             var makechg = false;
             if (changes.length==0){
                   var s="No users selected to change roles.";
             }
             else {
                var s="Change\n";
                for (i=0; i<changes.length; i++) { 
                   var name= changes[i];
                   if(name.length == 2){
                         s+=name[0]+" to be "+name[1]+"\n";
                         makechg=true;
                   }
                   else{
                         if(changes.length==1) {
                            if(name[1]!=name[name.length-1]){
                                s="No users selected to change roles";
                                continue;
                             }
                             else{
                                 s+=name[0]+" to be "+name[name.length-1]+"\n";
                                 makechg=true;
                             } 
                          }
                         else{
                            if(name[1]!=name[name.length-1]){
                                continue;
                             }
                             else{
                                 s+=name[0]+" to be "+name[name.length-1]+"\n";
                                 makechg=true; } 
                         }
                      }
                  }
             }
             if (!makechg){
                   alert(s);
                   return false;
             }
             else {
                 var r = confirm(s);
                 if (r)
                      document.location.reload(true);
                 else{
                      document.getElementById("Action").value="nochg";
                      document.location.reload(true);
                 }
             }
       }
       </script><br><br><h1 align="center">User list</h1>
<form id="form_user_list" class="form_user_list" name = "form_user_list" method="post" 

action="edit_users.php">
<div id="user_list" class="datatable_container">
<table class="admin_table display" id="users_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th rowspan="2">Name</th>
<th colspan="2">Current Role</th><th rowspan="2" width="50">Delete User</th>
</tr>
<tr><th width="80">Admin</th>
<th width="80">User</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a title="igor">igor</a></td>
<td><div><input type="radio" checked  name="radio_10" onchange="chgRadio('igor','2')" value="2"></input></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="radio_10" onchange="chgRadio('igor','1')" value="1"></input></div></td>
<td><img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="delConfirm('10','igor')"></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a title="nate">nate</a></td>
<td><div><input type="radio" checked  name="radio_9" onchange="chgRadio('nate','2')" value="2"></input></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="radio_9" onchange="chgRadio('nate','1')" value="1"></input></div></td>
<td><img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="delConfirm('9','nate')"></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a title="shahm6">shahm6</a></td>
<td><div><input type="radio" checked  name="radio_4" onchange="chgRadio('shahm6','2')" value="2"></input></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="radio_4" onchange="chgRadio('shahm6','1')" value="1"></input></div></td>
<td><img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="delConfirm('4','shahm6')"></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a title="test">test</a></td>
<td><div><input type="radio" checked  name="radio_11" onchange="chgRadio('test','2')" value="2"></input></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="radio_11" onchange="chgRadio('test','1')" value="1"></input></div></td>
<td><img src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="delConfirm('11','test')"></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

.try to remove the checked word in the first radio button.try to test if it work.because I cant get the idea that you want to express because you did not include a link for that,like jsfiddle.net..

happy coding...